# Does Xcode Interface Builder support plugins?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Does Xcode Interface Builder support plugins? From what I found, it was supported up until Xcode 3 and then dropped in Xcode 4.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

It has some kind of limited support, but most of the old plugins are stopped working properly for since long time ago and the biggest limit introduced with Xcode8.

You can make some of them working by disabling SIP which is **NOT** recommended at all. And some other has updated version for newer Xcodes.

Some of the IB plugins are actually codes that Xcode uses directly from the source code to generate tools in the inspector section that you can check out by research about `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable`.

These are some general history of Xcode but the best option you have is to search for the specific plugin support or specific use case you need to build a plugin.